# Using Laravel, how can I retrieve records through a pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a User model and a Group model, connected by a pivot table.  Users can be in many groups, groups contain multiple users.

I need to retrieve all of the users that are in a given group.  Here are my models and my controller code so far.  I'd appreciate any help - I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  My error messages vary depending on what I try, but with the current code it's:

"BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1992: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::users()"

Many thanks!

User:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
    {  
    //BLAH BLAH  
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');        
    }
}
```

Group:

```
class Group extends Model
{
protected $table = 'groups';

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'detail'      
];

public function scopeName($query, $group)
{
    $query->where('name', '=', $group);  
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');        
}

}
```

Controller Code:

```
public function getGroup($query) 
{
    // $query = "name of group" FYI       
    // The task of this function is to return a Datatable object containing all users in the given ($query) group

    $the_group = Group::with('users')->Name($query) -> get();
    dd($the_group->users);  
    return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
}
```

Comment: you have `$the_group->users`, not `$the_group->users()`.  You're not calling the function `users()`, you need to change it to `dd($the_group->users());`, unless I'm mistaken (never used laravel before, maybe it's specific syntax to that)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  With users() or users()->get() I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::users() instead.

Comment: @EdFearon you are missing the get method on you query scope, hence the error message. see my answer below.

Comment: Hello.  I've seen and added it.  See my reply below.  The query returns the collection which contains the users, but I don't know the proper syntax to return them.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends Model
{
   public function scopeGender($query){
       return $query->where('gender', 'f');
   }
}
```

> Utilizing A Query Scope
>   Once the scope has been defined, you may call the scope methods when querying the model. However, you do not need to include the scope prefix when calling the method. You can even chain calls to various scopes, for example:

```
$users = App\User::gender()->get() or -> first(); //<-- notice that you still need to 
chain get or first to fetch results.
```

That's one error you have in query. your query should look like this.

```
 $the_group = Group::with('users')->Name($query) -> get();   
 //returns all rows. use a foreach loop.


 $the_group = Group::with('users')->Name($query) -> first(); 
 // returns first

 echo $the_group -> users;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks - I tried your version but I'm still getting the same problem.  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$users

Comment: That being said when I use your query and dd($the_group); I can drill down and find the users within the collection.  It just doesn't accept my calls to users...  Not sure how to proceed.  Any thoughts?  Seems like it's close.

Comment: @EdFearon you are using get and it's return all rows so you have to loop through the array one at time, or you just want a single row use first instead.